# Xamarin Forms to Native using PageRenderer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am creating my first Cross-Platform Xamarin Forms application (PCL) using VS 2015. Application needs some native views/controls so I decided to use PageRenderer. I know, I cannot override Activity operations (*onBackPressed, finish, onResume*) in PageRenderer for Android project. So is there any alternative to achieve same functionality? For example, I need to start some animation in **onResume** and want to show some messagebox in **onBackPressed** operation.
Please guide me.

Also existing native application used xml files for offline data support. Will it be a good option to use SQLite with Xamarin Forms (cross-platform) application for storing data? Please need expert opinion.